# Issues booting VM

Tags: redhat, virtual-machines, command-line-interface, vmware-vsphere, linux-kernel

I am new to Linux, and have inherited a VM that is running centos. It sat idle for about 2 years with no-one touching it. I have run some updates to get the system up-to-date. I think I accidentally did something in my newb attempts and now I cannot get the vm to boot, it just goes into emergency.

Linux Version 3.10.0-693.e17.x86_64 Centos
Red Hat 4.8.5-16

I get the below error/s in journalctl:

```
localhost rpcbind[273]: Cannot open file = /run/rpcbind/rpcbind.xdr for writing
localhost rpcbind[273]: Cannot save any registration
localhost rpcbind[273]: Cannot open file = /run/rpcbind/portmap.xdr for writing
localhost rpcbind[273]: Cannot save any registration
```

```
localhost iscsid[2348]: can't open InitiatorName configuration file /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi
localhost iscsid[2348]: Waring: InitiatorName file /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi does not exist or does not contain a properly formatted InitiatorAlias
localhost iscsid[2348]: can't open iscsid.safe_logout configuration file /etc/iscsi/iscsid.conf
```

```
localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Switch Root
```

```
localhost kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
```

[ISCSID Image as recommended from txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLHeW.png)

[Root Switch Error Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJS4P.png)

Please understand I am completely new to this system, but have no option but to work with it. Any assistance in fixing this would be fantastic.

Appreciate it.

R

Comment: How does the virtual machine boot? From the network? Is the network available? It looks like it might want to reach a remote iSCSI target. Track down that target to see what it is and if it is up. Finally, look at the errors that the system logs in rdsosreport.txt when it goes into emergency mode.

Comment: Hi @michael hampton, 
Assuming I am understanding you correctly. The VM is in a farm - if that means anything. I have a feeling I changed the PATH by accident... I don't know if this could be causing it.  After checking the rdsosreport it only has two lines ```` [75818.946380] blu_update_request: I/O error,dev fd0,sector 0 [75819.034357] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector ````. I'm sorry if I am unhelpful! I have been trying to boot it using an ISO file, to no avail to repair, not sure if this will work.

Comment: That just means it can't read the floppy disk. Your VM has no floppy disk. You can ignore that. Look at the places where I recommended previously.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have tried to do as you suggested and put some images in the existing question for you to check. I'm unsure if this is what you mean. Also, I can only get into emergency, so I have limited functionality and am unable to check much of the iscsi information. Not sure on a way around this.

Comment: At this point I suggest you rollback to the snapshot you made before doing the upgrade. Then you can at least look at the working system and try to figure out how it is supposed to be working.

Comment: @MichaelHampton unfortunately, being completely new, I only found out about snap shots through my research on how to fix/resolve the issue. The person prior did not set up automatic ones either, So i cannot roll-back this way. There is no actual data on this machine yet anyway, so I am not opposed to any suggestions that mean losing data.

Comment: If this VM wasn't doing anything anyway, you could just delete it and start over.

Comment: I think you need to focus on error "Root Switch Error Info" more than ISCSI error.

Comment: @SunilBhoi I think I found the I am missing init.d and rc.d